# Cloud Composer 2 unable to send SMTP emails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am struggling in sending a email from cloud-composer 2 environment(composer-2.0.11-airflow-2.2.3) via smtp.gmail.com.

Please find my configs below :

Note I tried using smtp_password_cmd and smtp_password_secret but both give the same error.

I have also setup a network connectivity test which shows smtp.gmail.com is reachable from my VPC

```
Error Msg:

File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 310, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
raise err
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

[image]

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This timeout error seems to be more a network issue rather than a misconfiguration, can you check if your pods reach the smtp server and vice versa?

Comment: The error **Cannot assign requested address** means you either do not have permission or the port is already being used. This part of the stack trace **timeout** indicates that the port is already being used by another software or service.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't think port is a issue since I am able to get an smtp_object when running from local. However from local I get an Auth issue.

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza can you suggest ways to debug. Since I have setup a network rule which allows all egress to port 587 from any instance within my project

Comment: First please confirm if you set up a [Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/private-ip) in your composer environment and check if this has connectivity to your API Endpoint? Then follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/configuring-private-ip) to check the network and the Ip’s of your nodes and pods. If you used a shared VPC do this [checklist](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-vpc-sc#network_configuration_checklist).

Comment: You can follow the steps 1-4 in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#viewing_installed_python_packages), once you are on step 4, you’ll have a terminal on the pod so you can run a command to check the connectivity to the smtp server.